# How to add a CSS file to index using HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack, stylus, html-webpack-plugin

I have the following structure

```
src
  angular
    ...
      test.ts
      test.pug
      test.styl
  stylus
    main.styl
```

Currently I use the HtmlWebpackPlugin to add the angular folder to the application. Now I want a way to include just the main styles, after transpilation, in the template. I looked at the documentation and it doesn't seem like I can export provides an extension only a [name](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I did this by including the stylus-loader, style-loader, and css-loader...

```
 {
    test: /\.styl$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader"
 }
```

Then just include it as a separate chunk

```
entry: {
  ...
  styles: ['my.styl']
},
```

It will be a JS file but still load on page load.